# Why non-blocking TCP socket would spend a lot of time in ::write() call?

Tags: sockets, tcp

For non-blocking TCP socket, I expect `write()` or `read()` will return immediately in any case (whether `read()` can fill buffer or not, whether `write()` can send entire buffer or not).

Is there some real world circumstances that lead to `write()` working noticeabe amount of time (milliseconds) in non-blocking mode?

Comment: Unclear whether you are asking *why* this happens or *whether* this *can* happen. Are you experiencing this, or is it just a theoretical question? 'Noticeable' isn't defined in milliseconds, it is defined in percentage of execution time.

Comment: When you keep calling it over and over until it succeeds...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason was simple: thread starvation. The virtual machine was stealing time from my code: for example, usleep(30000) might return after 800 milliseconds.